# Can anyone explain one formula in the derivation of a branching process example?

Tags: probability

I am reading the branching process example from chapter 0 of Probabilities with Martingales by Williams.

What confused me is equation 0.8(c) on page 10. How is this formula derived?

$Z_n$ represents the distinction probability of the branching process. $M_n := Z_n/\mu^n$ and $\mu$ is the expectation of the number of children any parent reproduces. It is shown in a previous section that $M_n$ is a martingale.

The relevant section is pasted below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f_{n+1} = f \circ f_n$, so $$f_{n+1} \left( \exp \left(- \frac{\lambda}{\mu^n} \right) \right) = f \left( f_n \left(\exp \left( -\frac{\lambda}{\mu^n}\right) \right) \right).$$

On the left-hand side, we have $$f_{n+1} \left( \exp \left(- \frac{\lambda}{\mu^n} \right) \right) = f_{n+1} \left( \exp \left(- \frac{\mu\lambda}{\mu^{n+1}} \right) \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left(-\lambda \mu M_{n+1} \right)\right)$$ by equation (b).

On the right-hand side, we have $$f \left( f_n \left(\exp \left( -\frac{\lambda}{\mu^n}\right) \right) \right) = f \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(-\lambda M_n \right) \right) \right).$$  Putting this together, we have $$ \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left(-\lambda \mu M_{n+1} \right)\right) = f \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(-\lambda M_n \right) \right) \right).$$

Taking $n \to \infty$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the derivation. Can you explain the formula intuitively? Seems like most numbered equation in this book have a good intuition behind it

Comment: @user1559897,  I don't have any intuition for these sorts of things; very often intuition is a necessary part of probability, but occasionally you just need to chug through some manipulation to get a result that is intuitive.  There's no guarantee that the steps in between will make sense in any intuitive way.